# how to send array from controller to view

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a array in controller I have to send it to view and then show the value

**The Controller page code**

```
 public function showbookedmenu(){

 $rowLength=$this->input->post('rowno');
 $check=$this->input->post('checkeed');

    $j=0;
    for($i=1;$i<=$rowLength;$i++)
    {
        $check=$this->input->post('checkeed'.$i);

        if($check== "checked")
        {
        $orderedItem[$j][$i]   = $this->input->post('txtMenuItem'.$i);
        $orderedItem[$j][$i+1]  = $this->input->post('quantity'.$i);
        $orderedItem[$j][$i+2]    = $this->input->post('lebPrice'.$i); 
        $orderedItem[$j][$i+3]= $this->input->post('grandtotal'.$i); 
        $j++;
        }
        else{}
    }
    $data['order']= $orderedItem;
    $this->load->view('orderpage', $data);
 }
```

**The view page**

`What will be the code??`

Comment: Do `print_r($order)` in your view, see the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First rewrite your controller action like this:

```
public function showbookedmenu()
{
  $rowLength = $this->input->post('rowno');    
  $orderedItem = array();

  for($i = 1; $i <= $rowLength; $i++)
  {
    $check = $this->input->post('checkeed'.$i);

    if($check == "checked")
    {
      $orderedItem[] = array(
        'menu_item' => $this->input->post('txtMenuItem'.$i),
        'quantity' => $this->input->post('quantity'.$i),
        'leb_price' => $this->input->post('lebPrice'.$i),
        'grand_total' => $this->input->post('grandtotal'.$i)
      );
    }
  }

  $data['order'] = $orderedItem;
  $this->load->view('orderpage', $data);
}
```

Then in your view you can do this:

```
<? foreach($order as $order_item): ?>
  <? echo $order_item['menu_item']; ?>
  <? echo $order_item['quantity']; ?>
  <? echo $order_item['leb_price']; ?>
  <? echo $order_item['grand_total']; ?>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

first try to print array value in your view file..

```
print_r($order);
```

if it is coming fine..

you can give it on

```
foreach ($order as $value):
```

and use it :

Comment: Hello **orderpage** is the view page name not the array

Comment: This is CodeIgniter: the data passed to the view will be in `$order` not in `$data`.